# Save the edit when running a Sublime Text 3 plugin

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

For understanding what I'm trying to achieve :  printing delayed text in another view...

I'm trying to make this sublime text 3 plugin run properly I want to call multiple method of my class using the edit passed in parameter of my run method as so :

```
# sample code, nothing real
class MyCommandClass(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    myEdit = None
    def run(self, edit):
        self.myEdit = edit
        # stuff
        self.myMethod()

    def myMethod(self):
        # use self.myEdit ...
```

And I try to use it later on another method, but when I execute the plugin I get  this error :
`ValueError: Edit objects may not be used after the TextCommand's run method has returned`

For what I understand, all use of the edit object must be before the run command has returned. And as I'm playing with `set_timeout`, it might not be the case... So what can I do ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Solution found, to pass an argument to another view and use the edit :

```py
class MainCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        newFile = self.window.new_file()
        newFile.run_command("second",{ "arg" : "this is an argument"});

class SecondCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, argument):
        # do stuff with argument
```

Comment: I assume you actually mean `sublime.set_timeout(lambda:  newFile.run_command(...), 1000)`